# Snowflake - FLATTEN() - How does it work internally?

Tags: sql, arrays, json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, flatten

I am learning Snowflake right now, and the way FLATTEN() works is a bit counter intuitive.

A simple query.

```
SELECT
    raw:first_name::STRING AS FName,
    raw:last_name::STRING AS LName,
    f.value::STRING AS Skill
FROM tbl,
    TABLE(FLATTEN(raw:Skills)) f
ORDER BY raw:id::INT
LIMIT 5;
```

Elegantly, it flattens the `Skills` array and returns this.

| FNAME | LNAME | SKILL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Flossy | Fasson | PS3 |
| Flossy | Fasson | Vlookup |
| Flossy | Fasson | Go |
| Celeste | Hubert | Tcl-Tk |
| Celeste | Hubert | Zines |

My questions are:

1. Does Snowflake just infer that the source of `raw:Skills` is table `tbl`, as table name is not explicitly expressed here?
2. How does Snowflake align the array (as the right table) to the left table? It looks like a Cross Join with no join keys, if so, every array should be joined to each and every row on the left and result in incorrect alignment.

Answer (score 1):

> Does Snowflake just infer that the source of raw:Skills is table tbl, as table name is not explicitly expressed here?

```
SELECT
    raw:first_name::STRING AS FName,
    raw:last_name::STRING AS LName,
    f.value::STRING AS Skill
FROM tbl, 
    LATERAL TABLE(FLATTEN(input=> tbl.raw:Skills)) f
```

Related: [Lateral Join](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/join-lateral)

Answer (score 0):

the first question is same "inference" as when you use a column name but do not use table name or the alias, thus these are all the same:

```
select a 
from table_name
```

```
select a 
from table_name as t
```

```
select t.a 
from table_name as t
```

```
select table_name.a 
from table_name
```

now when this gets tricky is if two tables have the same column name, you must say which one you want

```
select id 
from table_a_name
cross join table_b_name
```

if they both have an `id` this will not compile.

In some databases if you join on id between two tables:

```
select id 
from table_a_name
join table_b_name 
   on table_a_name.id = table_b_name.id
```

this is valid, but not in Snowflake.

the FLATTEN is like a LEFT JOIN every input row is match to every expanded row, and both sources and the flatten objects (and you can do many FLATTEN and it just combinations, aka cross joins all the way down).

the comma method you have show is the "old SQL style" and the new style would be a CROSS JOIN, but LATERAL is also valid as that is more akin to what is happening. Snowflake support mean dialects from other RMDBs, to make porting SQL easier, but it does not cover all cases.

Comment: Ah, I see. Just to be sure my understanding is right. 
Each flattened array only CROSS JOINs the corresponding row on the left so that "PS3", "Vlookup", and "Go" CROSS JOIN "Flossy Fasson" and doesn't meddle with "Celeste Hubert". 
Is this correct?

Comment: I do t see you data but you had row 1 `”a”, 1, [10,11,12]` and row 2 `”b”, 2, [20,21,22]` and you flatten the third element you would get six rows, 3 a,1,10 a,1,11 a,1,12 and 3 of b,2,20 b,2,21 b,2,22. Thus the lateral idea on “using local information”